# How can I get the module files links and use it in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, module

I'm having a problem wherein I want to animated my text but I want to pass a module of javascript which is [THIS](https://tobiasahlin.com/moving-letters/#2). There is a link of how I can add this in js but I cannot call the module of the link here is my code sample

```
For the outside of function
    function AnimationLibrary(url){
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = url;
        script.async = true;
        console.log(url)
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    // This is for text color animation css
    useEffect(() => {
        var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.introduction .text h4');
        textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");
    
        anime.timeline({loop: true})
          .add({
            targets: '.ml2 .letter',
            scale: [4,1],
            opacity: [0,1],
            translateZ: 0,
            easing: "easeOutExpo",
            duration: 950,
            delay: (el, i) => 70*i
          }).add({
            targets: '.ml2',
            opacity: 0,
            duration: 1000,
            easing: "easeOutExpo",
            delay: 1000
          });
    },[])
And the return in function 
return (
            {AnimationLibrary(
                "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"
            )}
)
```

Yes I can see the link in my console.log but the problem is I cannot get the module of the link of the link that I give in first line.. Anyway this is my source of how I can get the external link
[THIS](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-include-an-external-javascript-library-to-reactjs/)
Any idea how can I get the modules of the link for animating my letters in react hooks? It would be a big help to me thank you.

**EDITED**
S**SOMEONE PLEASE HELP ME HERE I"M STUCK I DON"T KNOW HOW TO DO IT**

Comment: Did you try adding `script.type = "module"`?

Comment: can you explain it? I don't know how to do that so. Or try to demo it hehehe.

Comment: @CesarePolonara it gives me an error like this `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'anime')
`

Comment: Try `script.setAttribute('type', 'module');`